# Get arguments from NSBlock object

Tags: ios, arguments, objective-c-blocks

I have a **NSGlobalBlock** object which inherites from NSBlock class. I would like to explore its arguments (types and values of each argument)

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? Have you tried anything? Code and your problem?

Comment: `
typedef void (^CompletionHandlerBlock)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error);

CompletionHandlerBlock obj;
.....
obj(response,data,error);//response, data and error are being initialised
`

I would like to know how to access to response, data and error outside of this code. How to debug argument values. Is that clear ?

Comment: This link can help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1

Comment: A block is a callable thing, like a function. It has parameters, each with a type. It doesn't have the values of arguments, since those are passed by the caller when someone calls it. What exactly are you asking about?